# How to use a generic const value in a function with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

In TypeScript, this is perfectly legal :

```
function getFoo<P = "a"|"b">():string {
    // P is a type, not a value!
    return "foo";
}

getFoo<"a>">();   // no errors!
```

Is there a use case for this and, if so, how to use the `P` type inside that function, whether it is `"a"` or `"b"` ?

Comment: The use case for what you wrote?  Not sure, it doesn't look very useful.  You've just made `P` [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `"a" | "b"`; you haven't [constrained it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Did you mean `P extends "a" | "b"` instead?

Comment: @jcalz the use case is irrelevant. It is possible to do this in TypeSript and I want to understand why. That's the point of the question.

Comment: You asked "What is the use case for this" and now say "the use case is irrelevant".  I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here.  Could you [edit] to not ask about the use case if it's irrelevant and instead be explicit about what you're asking?  If some piece of that example code is your focus could you mention it?  Right now the question reads to me like "It is legal to walk around in public wearing a winter coat in the summertime; why is that allowed and what good does it do?" I currently don't know how to answer this other than ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz please step back and try to view the question differently than with your bias? I mentioned that I have no use case for this, so I will not provide a use case for this; my use case for this is irrelevant. However I DO want to know if there can be a use case for this.

Comment: I have not asked you for a use case.  My first comment was meant to be read like "you're asking us to tell you the use case for some example you wrote? It doesn't look useful to me."  Anyway, if you decide to [edit] the question to make the question more clear I'll take a look; otherwise we are probably at an impasse and it wouldn't be fruitful to engage further.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz question edited. The original intent is still there.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what you're looking for. On the face of it, **there is no discernible use case for that code**; it's doing some weird unmotivated things (e.g., unused and unconstrained type parameter with a default), like entering a grocery store wearing pajamas and holding an open umbrella. I don't know why someone would do that; I can guess why someone might do *some* of those things but not all together. If you want to understand some *piece* of that code, please [edit] to point out what it is. I'm sure you're trying to ask something meaningful, but what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only used for typing things. If you want to actually do anything with the value, you need to use regular parameters for that. You can do something like this:

```
function getFoo<P extends "a" | "b">(value: P): string {
    // P is a type, not a value!
    return "foo";
}

getFoo("a");
```

With this example, `value` is restricted to "a" or "b" like if you had done `value: "a" | "b"`. However, you now have a type that you can use that will match the parameter type, which you could use in a return type or another parameter or anywhere else within that function.

Comment: Thank you, and I am aware of this. If TypeScript allows writing this kind of code, then there must be a reason, or some use case. Answering something different does not help me understand why TypeScript allows this syntax! Or if the answer is "TypeScript allows it, but it does not help to do anything!", then the follow up question is "Then why does it allow this in the first palce?"

Comment: @YanickRochon If it's a followup question it might belong in its own post; if it's your primary question you might want to edit the original post to specify that instead of your existing question. But I'm not sure it would have an authoritative answer; TS couldn't possibly detect all situations in which a well-formed program is useless. Maybe you want a warning on an unused type parameter? If so that would be more of a linter rule and you might look into typescript-eslint's `no-unused-vars`.